# Hangman invalid syntax error

Tags: python, syntax-error

I keep getting invalid syntax error and it highlights the line of code with the words =  ' animals'.split() my code looks right I don't know what is causing this please help

```
import random
HANGMANPICS = ['''


  ''']
words = 'ant baboon badger bat bear beaver camel cat clam cobra cougar coyote crow deer dog donkey duck eagle ferret fox frog goat goose hawk lion lizard llama mole monkey moose mouse mule newt otter owl panda parrot pigeon python rabbit ram rat raven rhino salmon seal shark sheep skunk sloth snake spider stork swan tiger toad trout turkey turtle weasel whale wolf wombat zebra'.split()

def getRandomWord(wordList):

    wordIndex = random.randint(0, len(wordList) - 1)
    return wordList[wordIndex]
```

Comment: The code you posted doesn't raise any errors for me

Comment: could another part of the code cause that part to be highlighted in the error message?

Comment: That's certainly possible, considering you said "on to the next error message."  Can you post more of your code, and the full error message?

Answer (score 1):

I've executed your code (using python 2.7.11) and I didn't get any errors.

I've also execute the code on http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python_online.php
And it works fine.

I've added "print getRandomWord(words)" to your code, so when I execute it, I got different animal every time.

Please try to copy/paste my version and execute it in the online server:

```
import random
HANGMANPICS = ['''


  ''']
words = 'ant baboon badger bat bear beaver camel cat clam cobra cougar coyote crow deer dog donkey duck eagle ferret fox frog goat goose hawk lion lizard llama mole monkey moose mouse mule newt otter owl panda parrot pigeon python rabbit ram rat raven rhino salmon seal shark sheep skunk sloth snake spider stork swan tiger toad trout turkey turtle weasel whale wolf wombat zebra'.split()

def getRandomWord(wordList):

    wordIndex = random.randint(0, len(wordList) - 1)
    return wordList[wordIndex]

print getRandomWord(words)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not getting any errors either (python2.7.11 on Windows). Also, you might want to use triple quotes in your "words" so that you can cut the line length down to a more convenient level.

```
import random
HANGMANPICS = ['''


 ''']
words = '''ant baboon badger bat bear beaver camel cat clam cobra
cougar coyote crow deer dog donkey duck eagle ferret fox frog goat goose 
hawk lion lizard llama mole monkey moose mouse mule newt otter owl panda 
parrot pigeon python rabbit ram rat raven rhino salmon seal shark sheep 
skunk sloth snake spider stork swan tiger toad trout turkey turtle weasel
whale wolf wombat zebra'''.split() 

def getRandomWord(wordList):

    wordIndex = random.randint(0, len(wordList) - 1)
    return wordList[wordIndex]

 test = getRandomWord(words)
 print test
```

Comment: also I'm running python 3

Answer (score 0):

OK I got it, I had typed ''',''' instead of ''', ''' I guess python took issue with that. On to the next error message.